# UITableViewCell Separator not Appearing

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a UITableView in a custom VC which is pushed onto a custom navigation controller stack. The custom navigation controller has the following code:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0,335, 657);
}
```

The problem is, the separator lines between the cells do not appear. If I remove the bounds line, then they appear. Can I change the bounds and also have the separators show?

Calling viewWillLayoutSubviews after changing bounds is no help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so apparently this only happens on the simulator. Device is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are setting the bounds of the navigation controller's view, which you should never do. I suggest refactoring in a way that allows the navigation controller to manage its own view and the frame of its child view controllers' views.

Comment: I am presenting the navigation controller as a page sheet of that size. It seems like the only way to me. Can you please give me some details if its otherwise :)

Comment: On iOS 7, you can use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` to present a view controller with a custom size. Prior to iOS 7, there isn't a supported way to do this, and using unsupported methods may result in unexpected behavior.